# Google Custom Search Engine: "messy" query URL

Tags: google-search

I'm in the process of adding the Google Custom search engine on my blog, LonePlacebo.com, and noticed that the search query url that shows up looks like a mess like so:

http://loneplacebo.com/search-results/?cx=016164296208729675189%3Aqq4uaxnfgew&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&q=stanford&siteurl=loneplacebo.com%2F

But, when I tried the same CSE in CSS-Tricks, the url is much "cleaner" like so: 
http://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=css

Any ideas why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csstricks is using the custom search element.

You're still using the iframe option, which is no longer supported. Not sure how much longer it's going to work. [iframe deprecated](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70345)

Log-in to the Google CSE control panel and choose "results only" layout, this way, you can still use the same search box on your home page.

Once you switch, you can remove this: (which makes the "messy" url you speak of)

```
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="016164296208729675189:qq4uaxnfgew"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8"/>
```